# Repeated measures of multiple time series processes

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, autoregressive, state-space-models, dynamic-regression

I am struggling with a comparison of temporal processes, which are observed in several time series. The problem is as follows:

Suppose there are some semi-experimental conditions, with several observational processes running simultaneously or with a small lag (1-2% of each period’s length), producing a time series corresponding to each condition. The response variable is the same across conditions, standardized to z-scores.
Importantly, similar parallel observations are carried out repeatedly, but with varying and large gaps between each block (gaps being much longer than the time series of interest). This way, a meaningless seasonal pattern is introduced by the study design, possibly precluding a comparison of time series by condition identity alone.

To illustrate, below are 3 conditions observed in 4 blocks each:

[image: TS illustration]

The goal is to assess whether the time series at different conditions result from the same process, and if not, to assess which conditions share an underlying process.

Being a novice in time-series analyses, I am not sure how to address this problem. As far as I understand, a fitting approach in such cases is a multivariate auto-regressive state-space (MARSS) model, possibly with the condition identity incorporated as a process (unobserved) covariate, and the block's identity as an observation covariate (it seems to me that random effects as in (G)LMMs or GAMMs are inappropriate given the MARSS model structure).